# Mysql issue upgrading MyBB

Tags: mysql, sql, mybb

I'm trying to upgrade a MyBB forum and at the end of the upgrade I get this error message:

MyBB has experienced an internal SQL error and cannot continue.

SQL Error:
1146 - Table 'abualbd_mybb40.mybb_usertitles' doesn't exist
Query:
SELECT utid, posts, title, stars, starimage FROM mybb_usertitles ORDER BY posts DESC

What does it mean and how can I fix it? Thanks

I'm upgrading from 1.6.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no table in your database with name **mybb_usertitles**
And your sql query is trying to `SELECT` data from this table which doesn't exist.

A quick solution would be, if you go to your database and CREATE new table with name 
**mybb_usertitles**

```
CREATE TABLE mybb_usertitles (
utid int(11) auto_increment primary key,
posts text not null,
title varchar(255) not null,
stars varchar(255) not null,
starimage varchar(255) not null )
```